# Nested SQL query having select subquery in update statement

Tags: sql, asp.net, database

I get an error near `WHERE` clause on executing this query.

```
update AssetData set EmployeeName = ISNULL(EmployeeName,'') +@reasEmp 
where ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') 
and ID IN (SELECT ID FROM AssetData ORDER BY ID DESC
where ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') LIMIT 1)
```

Someone please help me to figure out what is wrong with this?

Comment: which database are you working on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
and ID IN (SELECT ID FROM AssetData ORDER BY ID DESC
where ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') LIMIT 1)
```

The `where` should become before `ORDER BY`. Although legal, `in ( ... limit 1)` doesn't make sense because `in` should be used with a list. I recommend using `= max(ID)` instead

```
and ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM AssetData where [AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%')
```

you could leave out the first part of your where clause since the ID matches the same criteria already

```
update AssetData set EmployeeName = ISNULL(EmployeeName,'') +@reasEmp 
where ID = (SELECT max(ID) FROM AssetData where [AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%');
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

i think your are using SQL SERVER

```
update AssetData set EmployeeName = ISNULL(EmployeeName,'') +@reasEmp 
where [AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%'
and ID IN (SELECT  TOP 1 ID FROM AssetData
where [AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%'
ORDER BY ID DESC)
```

Answer (score 1):

You had an `ORDER BY` prior to a `WHERE`.  Additionally, based on error message it's clear you're using SQL Server, so you need `TOP` instead of `LIMIT`:

```
update AssetData 
set EmployeeName = ISNULL(EmployeeName,'') +@reasEmp 
where ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') 
        and ID IN (SELECT TOP 1 ID 
                    FROM AssetData 
                    WHERE ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') 
                    ORDER BY ID DESC
                    )
```

Likewise you could choose `MAX()`:

```
update AssetData 
set EmployeeName = ISNULL(EmployeeName,'') +@reasEmp 
where ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') 
        and ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID)
                    FROM AssetData 
                    WHERE ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') 
                    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This if you want to select the latest added row according to ID

```
UPDATE AssetData set EmployeeName = ISNULL(EmployeeName,'') +@reasEmp 
WHERE([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') 
AND ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM AssetData
where ([AssetNumber] like'%" + WA_number.Text + "%') LIMIT 1)
```

Comment: Error - " The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP or FOR XML is also specified"

Comment: Yeah that works fine but I want it to select the last ID (latest added row) from my table where AssetData = ...  that's why I need the DESC